# Quebrar um arquivo txt em vários itens em uma lista de string

Tags: c#

Tenho um arquivo txt com 2000 nomes. Quando eu carrego em uma lista, o count é 1 e não 2000. Claro, pois como se trata de um arquivo texto é apenas 1. Acontece, que o arquivo está organizado com `\n\r` dentro dele. Mesmo eu dando um `Split()`, mesmo assim não consigo carregar uma lista com 2000 registros ou itens. Como eu faço isso? Ou seja, pegar um arquivo txt e dividi-lo em uma lista de string com vários itens, usando como separador o `\n\r`?

Usei esse código para preencher o array que vem do arquivo txt:

```
string[] text = new[] { System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path) };
```

Fiz dessa forma. Achei feio, mas não encontrei uma solução mais bonita, tive que fazer dois foreach e isso me deixa meio chato.

```
string[] text = new[] { System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path) };

            foreach (var item in text)
            {
                string[] linha = item.Split('\n');
                foreach (var i in linha)
                {
                    lista.Add(i);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Não soube como preencher o array `linha` em uma única vez. Fiz o `foreach`, pois ele sempre vai passar uma única vez, mas é meio amedrontador isso. O certo seria carregar o array `linha` em uma única vez, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 3):

Poderia fazer assim:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
List<string> texto = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode percorrer todo o txt com sua String gigante e alimentar a lista para cada unidade encontrada.

Se o separador é \n\r, percorra sua String procurando por esse separador e use Substring pra passar cada um dos itens para a lista.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextReader _Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\ArquivoTexto.txt");

string[] _Splitado = _Reader.ReadToEnd().Split('|');

List<string> _Lista = new List<string>(_Splitado);
```

Isso resolve? Só trocar o nome do arquivo e o caracter que quer usar como separador.